# .Net Maui Fill Top-Tabbar Horizontal

Tags: android, .net, maui, mvvm-toolkit

Is it possible to fill the horizontal space with only two tabbar-items on Mobile?
At the moment the items are aligned on the left, I would like to have them stretched over the whole possible space.

**TopBar Image**

[image]

Shell xaml:

```
<FlyoutItem FlyoutDisplayOptions="AsMultipleItems">
    <Tab Title="NFC-Toolkit" >
        <ShellContent 
            Title="Read" 
            Route="Read"
            ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate view:ReadPage}"/>
        <ShellContent 
            Title="Taglists" 
            Route="TagLists"
            ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate view:TagListPage}"/>       
    </Tab>
    
</FlyoutItem>
```

I have already searched for some time in the documentation and found nothing about it.

I want it to be like this:
**Topbar expectation**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is achievable by using a custom handler so that you can stretch over the whole horizontal space with even width.

You can refer to the detailed steps below:

1.Create a custom ShellRenderer class:`CustomShellHandler` under Platform/Android:

```
public class CustomShellHandler : ShellRenderer
{
      public CustomShellHandler(Context context) : base(context)
      {
      }

      protected override IShellTabLayoutAppearanceTracker CreateTabLayoutAppearanceTracker(ShellSection shellSection)
      {
           return new MyTabLayoutAppearanceTracker(this);
      }
}

public class MyTabLayoutAppearanceTracker : ShellTabLayoutAppearanceTracker
{
       public MyTabLayoutAppearanceTracker(IShellContext shellContext) : base(shellContext)
       {
       }
       public override void SetAppearance(TabLayout tabLayout, ShellAppearance appearance)
        {
            base.SetAppearance(tabLayout, appearance);
            // the key is to set the TabMode and TabGravity
            tabLayout.TabMode = TabLayout.ModeFixed;
            tabLayout.TabGravity = TabLayout.GravityFill;
        }
}
```

2. In `MauiProgram.cs`, register the `CustomShellHandler` as below:

```
     .ConfigureMauiHandlers(handlers => {
#if ANDROID

       handlers.AddHandler(typeof(Shell), typeof(CustomShellHandler));
#endif
});
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Tanks for your answer it works fine.
However, one thing is unclear to me:
what is the best practice for the reference the new Custom Platform Class in mauiProgram.cs ?

Comment: @FlorianRedl My pleasure! Do you mean how to register the handler in `MauiProgram.cs`, if so, you can refer to:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/handlers/create#register-the-handler